# Profile picture with bottom grey banner after a new upload

Tags: bug, images, profile-picture, uploader

I have just found that after uploading a new profile picture which is not corrupt and does not have a grey banner at the bottom, that in some places it appears to:

[image: Grey banner on profile picture in some places]

As you will see the grey banner is different on the two images showing my profile picture in the screenshot above.

I have found that this issue occurs on [my main SE profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5384477/paranoid-panda) as well, although not in chat, and most other places such as my AskUbuntu chat profile seem to be fine and show the proper image. It should also be noted that when I uploaded the new profile picture it appeared as completely blank (white) in the settings where one clicks to upload a new one. The image I uploaded is a jpg.

I asked someone else if they could check, and they [said](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34053173#34053173) that they could also see the grey banner, though not in the places where I can see it.

I believe that this happened before, in the past in order to get a picture with no grey banner at the bottom I had to reupload it several times, fortunately however I only had to reupload it once in this instance.

Comment: An error with the upload on imgur's end, reuploading will fix and not much more SE can do

Comment: might be your cache as [i'm not seeing that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOEVG.png). i know that grey bottom half sometimes occurs when an image is missing data so it's possible your cache has some bad data in it

Comment: @Cai: But this always happens with profile picture uploads, yet I use the upload facility in questions and chat all the time and this never happens. Why would it be specific to the profile picture? And how come it's not on all the profile pictures, if it's imgur's side, then surely it would be all of them? Whereas depending on where on the site one goes, the grey things moves around from covering none of the profile picture, to a quarter, to half.

Comment: @Memor-X: I tried emptying that and refreshing several times. Plus others saw it too.

Comment: The reason it changes is because there are a number of different thumbnails generated at upload which are used in different places. As for why it happens to profiles images and not regular post uploads I have no idea, it's certainly an imgur issue though

Comment: Regular post uploads are not using the pre-generated thumbnails, so they're not affected. /cc @Cai